# How do you multiply a vector by a scalar and store it in another vector using a for loop

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

I have a vector

```
T=0.001;
Vm=1;

t=linspace(0,T,1001);
```

and I'm trying to use a for loop to create a vector v that will be based on

```
v(t) = (Vm/T) * t
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Why a loop? Have you tried [reading the documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/times.html)?

Answer (score 3):

Use [*element-wise multiplication*](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/times.html) , no  loops required

```
>> T=0.001;
>> Vm=1;
>> t=linspace(0,T,1001);
>> v = (Vm/T).*t; % v is 1x1001 double vector
            % ^ multiplies arrays element by element and returns the result in v.
```

Also, since `Vm/T` is a scalar quantity you don't need to use `.*`, just simply do :

```
>> v = (Vm/T)*t;
```

Comment: You don't even need `.*` to multiply a scalar with a vector. `mtimes` (`*`) is sufficient.

Comment: Solid answer now.  Makes you wonder why the OP didn't just try it...  :)